# UICollectionView AutoSize header height

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm coding for iOS 8+.

I have a `UICollectionReusableView` that's being used as header of `UICollectionView`

```
class UserHeader: UICollectionReusableView {
...
}
```

My View Collection does a few things:

Loads NIB in `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
resultsCollectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "UserHeader", bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "UserHeader")
}
```

Sets header height in `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection`.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSizeMake(0, 500)
}
```

However, my `UserHeader` view comprised of many UILabel, UIViews who's height changes at run time, how can I specify a height for `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection` that's dynamic? Or if I'm not supposed to use `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection` for auto-sizing in iOS 8+, please let me know what I should use. Thanks in advance.

For completeness sake, here's how I load the view, but I'm not sure if that's relevant for this discussion:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String!, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UICollectionReusableView! {
    var reusableview:UICollectionReusableView = UICollectionReusableView()
    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
        let userHeaderView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "UserHeader", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UserHeader

                    ... extra code to modify UserHeader

                    reusableview = userHeaderView
    }
    return reusableview
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced a similar issue and fixed it by using `NSLayoutConstraint`s within the view to specify the height of the header view. Within the view controller I then configure the collection view's header thusly:

```
fileprivate var expectedSectionHeaderFrame = CGRect.zero
let headerIdentifier = "HeaderView"

func calculateHeaderFrame() -> CGRect {
    headerView.setNeedsLayout()
    headerView.layoutIfNeeded()

    let expectedHeaderSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height)

    return CGRect(origin: .zero, size: expectedHeaderSize)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    expectedSectionHeaderFrame = calculateHeaderFrame()
    return expectedSectionHeaderFrame.size
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    guard kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader else { fatalError("Unexpected kind of supplementary view in (type(of: self))") }

    let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    headerView.frame = expectedSectionHeaderFrame

    return headerView
}
```

Comment: where exactly are you implementing the `calculateHeaderFrame` ? where is headerView variable defined? What is the `headerView` ?